# String formatting does not behave as expected when using padding

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting

I am trying to form a text representation of a table based off of the result coming in from a SqlDataReader.

```
while (unitsRdr.Read())
{
    note.AppendFormat("{0,-15}", String.Format("{0}({1})", unitsRdr.GetValue(0), unitsRdr.GetValue(1)));
}
```

Now what I expect to happen is I should get 4 sets of items, that will have padding on the right hand side equal to 15. Like this

```
BP(mm\Hg)      HR(bpm)        RR(rpm)        Sa O2(%)       |<-- this would be the end of the string.
```

However what I am getting is

```
BP(mm\Hg          )HR(bpm            )RR(rpm            )Sa O2(%              )|<-- this is the end of the string.
```

It appears to start counting after the `(` and the `)` is put after the number of spaces.

What is the correct way of doing formatting so the text is like my first example?

---

For anyone who wants it here is the source table

```
desc         unit
------------ ----------
BP           mm\Hg     
HR           bpm       
RR           rpm       
Sa O2        %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the problem is that the value returned by `unitsRdr.GetValue(1)` is actually longer than you believe. I very much doubt that `string.Format` is doing that. Try using `unitsRdr.GetValue(1).Trim()` instead - or just test it with a hard-coded literal value.

Comment: I should delete this question out of embarrassment, I will accept after the 15.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I definitely wouldn't delete it - instead, I'd edit it to explain what exactly it turned out to be. Was it a fixed-width field in the database? Bad data? Something else? Save it for the next person in the same situation...

Comment: The column was char(15) instead of varchar(15) like I was expecting.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Right - that makes sense.